# Why does google map freeze page after a few post backs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, updatepanel

I am having the strangest problem.  I cant figure out why the google map on a site i'm building slowly freezes the page after about 5 or 6 post backs.  I'm currently using a calendar in an update panel, and the back and next buttons cause the google map to do strange things.  I've removed the update panel, and it still does the same thing.  After about 3 clicks the marker icon starts to slowy fuzz out and eventually turns black. Its making me nuts.  Any thoughts would be really helpful. THanks.  A link to a page with the problem is http://adkrenter.com/properties/106-plum-poppy-north and it does it in both ie and firefox.

Comment: I cant reproduce the error, can you run us through step by step?

Comment: If you hit the next button once then the prev button then the next button it starts getting funky after about 4 times.  Watch the marker icons they slowly get pixelated then turn black, then the page just starts freezing.  I had the next set to go ahead 5 years, but by the 5th year, it was done.

Answer (score 2):

Your underlying problem is that on each click to `Prev` or `Next`, you're adding 3 times the previous number of markers to the map at the same location.

I can't tell you *why* this is happening (or how to fix it) without seeing more code (it's painful wading through the page source so if you could post some relevant code for what you're doing on click, that might help)

**Update**

I looked at the response after about 7-10 clicks and it's a huge (relatively speaking, the initial response is only a few 10s of KB) 168 KB of which 143 KB is JavaScript code to add the same marker to the two maps on the page - 162 times each! It's no wonder the page freezes.

This is part of the response:

```
var GoogleMap1 = new Artem.Web.GoogleMap({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","BaseCountryCode":null,"ClientID":"ctl05_GoogleMap1","ClientMapID":"GoogleMap1","DefaultAddress":null,"DefaultMapView":0,"Directions":[],"EnableContinuousZoom":false,"EnableDoubleClickZoom":false,"EnableDragging":true,"EnableGoogleBar":false,"EnableInfoWindow":true,"EnableMarkerManager":false,"EnableReverseGeocoding":false,"EnableScrollWheelZoom":false,"EnterpriseKey":null,"Height":"130px","IsStreetView":false,"IsStatic":false,"Key":"ABQIAAAATFt6mjpmHxeLQ689NDV5WhTHwM4h-1LWnzPqjMrWYJQMyFF86hTACw-YJNmRQV0Dk4jcB3zQHvdUsw","Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MapEvents":{},"MarkerEvents":{},"MarkerManagerOptions":{"borderPadding":null,"maxZoom":null,"trackMarkers":null},"PolygonEvents":{},"PolylineEvents":{},"ShowMapTypeControl":false,"ShowScaleControl":false,"ShowTraffic":false,"StreetViewMode":0,"StreetViewPanoID":null,"Width":"190px","Zoom":14,"ZoomPanType":0});
GoogleMap1.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
GoogleMap1.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
GoogleMap1.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
//repeated a few hundred times

GoogleMap2.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
GoogleMap2.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
GoogleMap2.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
GoogleMap2.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
GoogleMap2.addMarker({"Address":"106 Plum Poppy North, Malta , NY, 12020","AutoPan":true,"Bouncy":false,"Clickable":true,"Draggable":false,"DragCrossMove":false,"IconAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"IconSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"IconUrl":null,"InfoWindowAnchor":{"X":0,"Y":0},"Latitude":42.968839,"Longitude":-73.777681,"MaxZoom":null,"MinZoom":null,"OpenInfoBehaviour":0,"ShadowSize":{"Height":0,"Width":0},"ShadowUrl":null,"Text":null,"Title":null});
//repeated a few hundred times

GoogleMap2.load();
```

I'm not familiar with .NET and C# so I can't really help much beyond this since I don't know how this 'update panel' works. But it seems like the problem lies with the server - it's sending back the same marker with a count that seems to be growing geometrically - the incoming number of markers is 3 times the previous number of markers.

Comment: Genius. Thank you.  I dont know the cause of the extra additions.  I will have to trace it out.  Thanks for the start.